# Acronym tags that have more than one interpretation e.g. IDE

Tags: discussion, tags

I was reviewing a proposed edit just now where the proposer was objecting to the use of the tag [`IDE`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ide/info) to mean a type of hard drive interface. The tag wiki for `IDE` has lots of information about Integrated Development Environments. So fair enough, probably a dodgy use of the tag, but on the other hand, `IDE` does also relate to hard drives.

Is there any precedent either way here? If someone actually wanted to use the tag to mean a type of hard drive interface, is it OK to use that tag even though the wiki description doesn't mention it? Do tags have to have only a single interpretation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging Very few tags succeed while leading two lives at once.

Comment: IDE is exactly the same thing as ATA version 1 (or is that now called PATA-1?), except that ATA-1 also includes XT-IDE and maybe IDE doesn't. And we have an [ATA] tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tags here have a specific meaning, which is usually explained in the tag wiki and when the popup hint appears when adding tags. If the question isn't relevant to that tag's description, the tag is inappropriate to use.

As you mention, the tag wiki for IDE clearly states that here it means *Integrated Development Environments*, which means use of it for the ancient HDD interface is inappropriate, and the tag should be removed. (When I edit a question to do so, I usually leave a comment explaining just that to the poster, so they'll know for future reference how to decide whether to add a tag or not.)

Comment: given your reputation score is about 16 times mine, I am inclined to take your word for it. When asking this question, in the back of my mind was the thought that programmers tend to obsess over details that really don't matter. Does it _really_ matter that a tag is used in a way counter to its wiki page? Does that in any way devalue the tag? Isn't the real value of a tag just to make things easier to find? How am I going to find information about IDE disks if the tag police forbid using it in that context?

Comment: @TimLong: Yes, it matters. And SO is a highly technical site, and *details* are very relevant. When someone is searching for information on an integrated development environment, they don't want to see a bunch of search results related to an HDD interface. When monitoring a tag for a specific topic, you don't want questions related to something different showing up in the list of questions. You can find questions about the IDE HDD interface by putting that in the search phrase. (Also, questions on the HDD IDE are most likely off topic here; they're probably more suitable for [su] instead.)

Comment: Thank you Ken, you have convinced me beyond all doubt.

Answer (score 2):

There is precedent:

- Most of the time (>99%), the question is simply mis-tagged. Correct that.
- Sometimes, the tag-wiki is wrong. Correct it. If it's not a clear-cut case, ask on meta.
- Sometimes, there are multiple equally valid candidates for owning the tag. Ask for disambiguation, or do it yourself (if small, easy and obvious enough). This means new tags for everything, and the old one is killed.
- Sometimes, there's a hostile take-over. Apple is especially good for that, look at swift.

Why insist that a tag only means one thing? Because they are used for categorization, and would become useless fast otherwise.

In this case, the predominant use is not the disk, and the tag-wiki is right. Deal with it.

The help-center has some more: https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging